# Listing long time work experience with interruptions due to education on a CV

Tags: resume, student

I'm currently studying computer science and am working part time at the same company for five years already (started at the place before I started university). However, I interrupted work for several times due to mandatory army service, an internship abroad and studying abroad. Furthermore, I tend to work full time in the summer holidays but only part time during the semester.

How do I list this on my CV so that this is clear to the person reading it?

I **don't** want it to look like this:

**Practical experience:**

Worked at company X from July to August 2007

Worked at company Y (abroad) from April to June 2008

Worked at company X from July to September 2008

Worked at company X from October 2008 to June 2009 part time

Worked at company X from July to September 2009

Worked at company X from July to September 2010

...and so on...

**Education**

Studied abroad from September 2009 to June 2010

**Additional information**

Mandatory army service from October 2007 to March 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part-time positions and internships, it's normal for there to be gaps.  You can list them together like this:

> Intern, Company X: summer 2007, summer 2008 through 2009, summer 2010
>
> Intern, Compny &, spring 2008

You can list the military service and study abroad as you did in your question or leave them out.  Are they relevant to the companies you're applying to?  Do they distinguish you in some useful way?

Comment: It depends. Companies in my country usually require male applicants to have completed the mandatory army service, so it is common to mention it on the CV. Studying abroad is usually a good thing, especially for engineering students like me.

Comment: @mort, it sounds like they're both relevant in your case, and there might even be standard ways to show the military service since most people will list it.  If you're a student, you can ask your placement office or advisor how that's usually done.